# Blank/white notification line on Android Pie

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-9.0-pie

We have a user complaining about the notifications being blank on a Pixel XL 2 running stock Android 9/Pie. When the user swipes down and expands the notification it shows up, and it is just fine after collapsing it afterwards again.

I haven't been able to find any information about anyone having similar problems. We send billions of push messages every month so it's a bit weird not having heard anyone else with this problem.

Please see attached screenshots:

[image: Blank line of notification]
[image: Blank group just after expansion]
[image: Group is shown correctly after expansion]
[image: Collapsed notification looks fine after being expanded]

**Is this a known issue? Are there any known workarounds? Or is it us doing something wrong?**

Comment: i am also pixel 2xl user. not a known issue. Please post your code. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: Maybe the app is doing something else on the main thread, it is a known issue with other apps. Or  maybe it is a silent push notification (if you use them) that is handled improperly by the android app side.

Comment: have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my app, I was using a custom view in Notification,

I have added below lines to overcome this issue

```
.setContentTitle("Your Title")
.setContentText("Your Message")
```

Hope this will help you